# Properties of conditional expectation

Tags: conditional-probability, expectation

In the probability book of Bauer it is claimed that for nonegative X and Y, or integrable X and Y we have
$$ (1) \quad  X=Y \, a.s. \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{A}) = \mathbb{E}(Y \mid \mathcal{A}) \, a.s.  $$
and 
$$ (2) \quad  X \leq Y \, a.s.  \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{A}) \leq \mathbb{E}(Y \mid \mathcal{A}) \, a.s..$$ I agree with this observation.

Now Bauer argues that if $(X_n)$ is a monotonously increasing sequence, then duo to $(1)$ and $(2)$ also $\mathbb{E}(X_n \mid \mathcal{A})$ can be seen as an increasing sequence.

I guess the term "can be seen as" refers to the fact that the conditional expectation is only almost surely given. But why do we need to use $(1)$ **and** $(2)$ to see that  $\mathbb{E}(X_n \mid \mathcal{A})$ can be seen as an increasing sequence ? Isn't $(2)$ sufficient? Usually when I read something like this I am missing something important.

Comment: (2) is sufficient. We have $X=Y$ ae **iff** $X\le Y$ ae. and $X \ge Y$ ae.

Comment: @copper.hat so you say (2) is sufficent, because (1) follows from (2). But we do not use (1) anywhere, right?

Comment: I am saying that if (2) is true, then (1) is true. So using (1) is equivalent to using (2) twice so to speak.

Comment: note that it is only true for L1 variables.

Comment: @mookid: That is a good point.

Comment: @mookid thanks for the note - I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for the claim it is not necessary to use $(1)$ additionaly to $(2)$.

However, if $(X_n)$ is only almost surely monotonously increasing, then one needs to use $(1)$ and $(2)$, because $(2)$ alone finds for each $n$ only a representative with $$ \mathbb{E}(X_n \mid \mathcal{A}) \leq \mathbb{E}( X_{n+1} \mid \mathcal{A}) $$
but the sequence of those representative $(\mathbb{E}(X_n \mid \mathcal{A}))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ does not have to be monoton increasing. In this case one would have to use $(1)$ together with the fact that the a countable infinite union of zero sets is again a zero set.